# When a vulnerability has been found affecting Linux Kernel, what should I do with Docker?

Tags: linux, security, docker, linux-kernel

Let's say that I have an Ubuntu host machine running Docker.

This host contains many running containers that use many various base images (`FROM`), such as ubuntu, alpine, java:8...

This host also contains some images built by hand.

Today, I am able to stop and remove all of my containers, then create all of them again. None of the images store data (I do not commit containers). Therefore losing my data is not an issue. Getting my services up again should not be an issue either as long as the images remain the same.

Assume a vulnerability has been found affecting the Linux Kernel.

I have updated my host OS so that the host is no longer vulnerable. Docker containers use the host's kernel to run, but is that enough? What are the considerations and actions I should take to make sure my containers are not affected by the vulnerability?

Comment: @shellter I considered posting it on serverfault or security, but neither of them seemed appropriate (serverfault being for professionals, and security did not seem to be a good candidate for this). I did not consider superuser nor unix, I'm gonna see which of the two fits better. I chose stackoverflow because of the huge amount of questions that already exist on SO about docker, even though docker has nothing to do with programming unless it's used for continuous integration.

Comment: I feel your pain (and possible frustration). IMHO, S.O. so dwarfs the other sites, it would be better just to rely on tags to to filter by topic. I think I read there had been a VM test site but it didn't get enough traffic, so it has been dropped. The primary reason I voted to close is your problem is very broad and lacks a testable case. Can you make something in less than 1 page of code/scripts that people can replicate your problem? Good luck.

Comment: I disagree. Dockerfiles are written by programmers and they must consider security issues in their implementation. For example a simple upgrade at the top ensure us every time a container is built it has latests security patches in libraries

Comment: In my industry, adding  automatic updates would get you fired (and you'd be firewalled from getting to the external internet anyway). ;-/ So as with most things in life, it depends. Also, this Q contained no code, so it didn't meet the expectations of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Thanks for your view! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since docker containers use the host kernel. Once the host kernel is updated you won't have problems with the containers.

Issues in libraries are another story. Openssl for example is a library which can be different in containers and the host and should be upgraded.

It is a good practice to include a `apt-get update && apt-get -q -y upgrade` at the top of your Dockerfile. So you should build your images regularly.

If you use official images it is good practice to make a pull regularly to upgrade your containers. If you use docker-compose:

```
docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d
```

It will upgrade them. For plain docker you need to make a pull. Delete the container and create a newer one pointing to the same volumes:

```
docker pull image
docker stop containerid && docker rm containerid
docker run image ....
```

Regards

Comment: Got contraversial feelings on your answer. While your passage about kernel is definitely true, official images experience may vary (for not so mainstream images). `apt update` will likely fail in Dockerfile in _this_  form

Comment: It was just an example used with ubuntu:xenial, using it with other distributions may fail. And yes you should use only official base images, like centos or ubuntu

Comment: Still, for apt-based distributions you should use commands like `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get --yes upgrade`.
I can provide you dozen of cases when using of 'official' docker images is impossible... Distribution betas, for example; openSUSE next

Comment: I don't understand your point, if you can't use official images, just be sure to keep them updated with the latest security patches in libraries. In short in my answer I say, for kernel the host, for libraries the container and of course the host

Comment: 1).  My passage about 'official images' was after yours _use only official images_. I believe you understand that's not always possible (and that I do understand you're talking about base images).
2). Another, much more significant note was about APT-driven package installation automation. Dockerfile will fail or emit load of errors every other time with simple `RUN apt-update`
3). I had no intention to say you're wrong. Just pointed you to some weak points in your answer


My previous comment could be a bit confusing itself, sorry for that

Comment: I will take note of `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. I have without this. Although they don't fail in fact they emit some errors about terminals or something like that.

Comment: DEBIAN_FRONTEND vairiable adjustment is just another way to suspend useless _apt_ non-interactive issues.
Your initial proposal was `apt upgrade` AFAIR.. which triggered me to comment. You've fixed it since. We're done discussing it I hope, good luck to you

Comment: I looked in my Dockerfiles and found the options. Same to you have a nice day / night